# Is there a way to drag QWidget over the QGraphicsView?

Tags: drag, qgraphicsview, qwidget

I want to drag custom items inherited by QWidget over the QGraphicsView? Any idea
Thanks

Comment: This question is very vague and most likely doesn't belong here. If you want help, please paste some examples of what you've been working on and what you've tried.

Comment: I tried to answer the question, but not sure if it is what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have a layout, you may give absolute position to your widgets, and then put any QWidget over any QWidget.